# Does Java's HashMap.get modify the map in any way?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hashmap

Okay, so this is a silly question. I recently found dead code along the lines of:

```
Something a = hashMap.get("key");
```

IntelliJ Idea was complaining that *a* was never used, so I told it to remove it. At that point it yelled at me, that removing the entire line could have side effects, and it offered me to leave it as:

```
hashMap.get("key");
```

Now that got me thinking, what are the potential side effects of *get*?

Comment: It's open-source: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.get%28java.lang.Object%29 (TLDR: no, it has no side effect)

Comment: There are no side effects. you can remove the line

Comment: I think that IntelliJ IDEA has skipped checking every method in the world for side effects and just assumes that methods may have side effects (not the worst of bets).

Comment: ...okay, I'm going to be pedantic: there is one possible way it could modify the `Map`.  You could actually have a `LinkedHashMap` that uses the access-order constructor to iterate in most-recently-accessed order.  The probability this is the case for your application is essentially nil.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, that would certainly be possible — but hardly the answer to the question, at least not as put in the title (said some other pedantic :-)

Comment: Well, LHM extends HashMap, so technically you could get a HashMap with that behavior.  /pedantry

Comment: That's an interesting possibility, but the object is definitely HashMap in my case. After some experimenting I agree with Ole V.V., it doesn't seem that Idea is trying too hard to prove that method call is side effect free. It can do it if the method is defined in the same file, at least.

Answer (score 1):

No, no side effects whatsoever!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any. The documentation does not mention any changes to map. I assume that it is yelling at you because you don't use `a` and it is an unnecessary variable. Hope this helps.